# service layer with data repository

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, service-layer

Can someone explain?
I'm trying to convert my wpf app mvvm into different layers (reading ddd). I have some small confusions

- Presentation Layer (WPF, WEB, API) (ok.. this I know )
- Entity Model (I know is the class that represent database table e.g
  customer {id,name,surname,phone} from Entity Framework

but the following confuse me

- Domain model (is the class that represent sql table columns? e.g
  customer {Id,Name,Surname,phone} or the class that make sense for my
  application e.g Customer {ID,FullName,Balance}
- Where domain model lives? in which layer (seperate dll ?, in service
  layer ? or in data repository dll)
- DTO (Data Transfered object) is it the same as domain model?
- Service Layer (is it a separate dll?)
- Business Layer (many times i see the word business layer, some
  refer it as service layer) what is it actually? is it the same? is it
  a different class? a different dll (layer) that has it's own
  responsibility apart from service layer?
- Data Repository (question is, if service layer or business layer should be implement in the same layer that repository lives)

with all the above i have make sample application trying to understand where each one goes.

STEPS I FOLLOW

1. I have sucesfully understant the data repository. a simple interface
   with CRUD and or complex queryies
2. I create a `IService` that implements and inherited from reposiroty
3. Now in wpf i have to reference the service dll, but wpf needs not only service dll but also repository dll because service layer is using it.

My Question on this is. Is It normal? shouldn't service be independent?

Should Service Layer used it's own models? and convert data repository models to service models? therefor wpf will not need reference to repository? ( but if so.. isn't duplicate work?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Domain model

It depends on which pattern you want implement: *rich domain model* or *anemic*.

Some refs:

- [DDD vs Anemic domain models](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2019/10/ddd-vs-anemic-domain-models/)
- [Anemic domain model](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)
- [Rich vs anemic domain model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314330/rich-vs-anemic-domain-model)

In two words:

- *rich domain model* - it's a model, when business logic incapsulated at your business object (model).
- *anemic domain model* - it's a model, when business logic implemented at service layer.

If you talks about services, it's not pure DDD, it's anemic.
Fowler told that anemic is an anti-pattern, but it's used a quite often. The main problem of rich domain model, that you need a lot of experience to realise right way to implement it.
I think in your case you can use entities as domain objects.

### Where domain model lives?

If you trying to implement domain model, it requires a organised structure of you solution.
Usually it contains next projects:

`*.Domain` - for domain objects
`*.Application` - for you business logic, if we talk about anemic model
`*.Dto` or `*.Contract` - for dto's or another objects that can be use at outer scope of your application (for services interactions, dto's,  etc.)
`*.Persistence` - for data layer

`Dto(Contract)` is placed in another project in case reusing items implemented at them.

Where * is your project name.

### DTO

Dto depends on your needs.
I recommend declare dto's for each purpose, but if you don't want, you still can return domain object (but some people can say, that it's bad practice).
As I told previously you can place dto's to *.Dto or *.Contract projects

### Service Layer and Business Layer

Implement at your `*.Application`

### Data Repository

Usually you prefer to declare Data Repository interfaces at `*.Domain` or `*.Application` and implementation at `*.Persistence`. It allows you use interfaces and don't care about realisation.

### Is it normal? shouldn't service be independent?

Best practice it's when service depends just on your `*.Domain` assembly.

### Should Service Layer used it's own models? and convert data repository models to service models? therefor wpf will not need reference to repository? ( but if so.. isn't duplicate work?)

You services should work with domain models, and return dto's when it needs. One of general ideas of ddd, that you have common model for all operations. So it's good if you can return your domain model from repository.

Comment: when we say persistence Layer. we mean the project that handles database? e.g where entity framework lives? or where sql commands executed to the server? therefor i guess the project should be based on latest .net framework and not .net standard .?

2. what we mean application layer? The presentation layer ? or just another layer for putting Business logic and service logic there and then > reference to presentation layer?